# What will happen if I try to output an object (by console.log) whose __proto__ prop is a proxy object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, console.log

```
const obj = {};

const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, propName, receiver) {
        console.log('propName', propName)
        return 1;
    },
});

const name = proxy.name;
const instance  = Object.create(proxy);
console.log('-----------');
console.log(instance);
console.log('-----------');
instance.a = 1;
```

I expect the output is

```
propName name
------------------
{}
------------------
```

but in fact, there are different result in different env

node v10.13.0

```
propName name
-----------
propName Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom) // why?
propName Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) // why ?
propName Symbol(Symbol.iterator) // why?
{}
-----------
```

chrome browser console

```
propName name
-----------
{}
propName Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) // why?
propName splice // why?
propName splice // why?
-----------
```

I think it was caused by console.log

what happened console.log in both env?

And why the {} at the back in node-v10.13.0 env , the {} in front in chrome console

it is my babelrc, the proxy is native code

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            {
                "decoratorBeforeExport": true,
                "legacy": true
            }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"   
    ]
}
```

[code and v10.13.0 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0irVQ.jpg)

[chrome output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOxq1.png)

Thanks!

Comment: `console.log` doesn't have a rigorously specified behavior, what it does is mostly left in the hands of whoever writes the related engine. While it could probably use some internal ways to scan objects without potential side effects, it's not too surprising, that it checks some properties directly (especially because of the nature of symbols - they are meant to be unique and clear, so a side-effect for a symbol known to do something else is not to be expected)

Comment: For seeing `standard output` - use `console.dir` and let us know if its as expected?

Comment: Why the `nodejs.util.inspect.custom` and `Symbol.toStringTag` symbols are accessed should be pretty obvious. `Symbol.iterator` and `splice` are probably accessed to test for an array-like object, which would be displayed differently. Why `splice` is accessed twice I cannot tell, but probably they just didn't bother caching the result of the check.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10731